# Pagination using Meteor Pages

Tags: javascript, meteor, pagination, meteor-blaze

I am trying to implement pagination using Meteor Pages in a template displaying all online users in my app.

`Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(Meteor.users, {
    itemTemplate: "Item",
    auth: function(skip, sub){
        var _filters = {'status.online' : true};
        var _options = {sort: {name: 1}};
        return [_filters, _options];
    },
    availableSettings: {
        perPage: true,
        sort: true,
        filters:true
    },
    perPage : 20,
    route: "/onlineusers/",
    router: "iron-router",
    routerTemplate: "onlineusers",
    templateName: "onlineusers",
});`

I am able to display all online users in my template using the above code block. Now, I want to filter the results further with parameters like age gender and country as provided from the client.  How can I use filters to further modify the results at the client. Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referring to the [documentation](https://github.com/alethes/meteor-pages/), you can pass a MongoDB find query object to the use the 'filters' property in your settings object.

For example:

```
 Pages = new Meteor.Pagination(Meteor.users, {
 ...,
 filters: {
   <name>: {
     $eq: <value>
   }
 },
 ...
});
```